# CDN do not allow me to convert mov video format to mp4

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I have tried so many thinks on stackoverflow but didn't fix my issue. So I am using following code for converting mov video format to mp4 video format. The code is working fine if I disable CDN but when I enable CDN then ffmpeg didn't work. What is wrong with CDN with the code below?

```
$cmd = shell_exec("ffmpeg -i video.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy video.mp4");
```

Command:

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.8 Copyright (c) 2000-2020 the FFmpeg developers built with gcc 4.8.5 (GCC) 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-39) configuration: --prefix=/usr --bindir=/usr/bin --datadir=/usr/share/ffmpeg --docdir=/usr/share/doc/ffmpeg --incdir=/usr/include/ffmpeg --libdir=/usr/lib64 --mandir=/usr/share/man --arch=x86_64 --optflags='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector-strong --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic' --extra-ldflags='-Wl,-z,relro ' --extra-cflags=' ' --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-version3 --enable-bzlib --disable-crystalhd --enable-fontconfig --enable-gcrypt --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcdio --enable-libdrm --enable-indev=jack --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-nvenc --enable-openal --enable-opencl --enable-opengl --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --disable-encoder=libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librsvg --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libv4l2 --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzvbi --enable-avfilter --enable-avresample --enable-libmodplug --enable-postproc --enable-pthreads --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --disable-debug --disable-stripping --shlibdir=/usr/lib64 --enable-libmfx --enable-runtime-cpudetect 
libavutil 55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100 libavcodec 57.107.100 / 57.107.100
libavformat 57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100 
libavdevice 57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100 
libavfilter 6.107.100 / 6.107.100 
libavresample 3. 7. 0 / 3. 7. 0 
libswscale 4. 8.100 / 4. 8.100 
libswresample 2. 9.100 / 2. 9.100 
libpostproc 54. 7.100 / 54. 7.100 
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1324920] stream 1, offset 0x24: partial file [mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x1324920] 
Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 480x360, 777 kb/s): unspecified pixel format Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, 
from 'https://dev.websiteaddress.com/uploads/files/2021-04-16/image_1618597539012465400_5.mov': Metadata: major_brand : qt minor_version : 0 
compatible_brands: qt creation_time : 2021-04-10T23:22:06.000000Z com.apple.quicktime.make: Apple com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone 12 Pro com.apple.quicktime.software: 14.4.2 com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2021-04-11T07:22:06+0800 Duration: 00:00:02.73, bitrate: N/A Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), none(smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 480x360, 777 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 1200 tbc (default) Metadata: creation_time : 2021-04-10T23:22:06.000000Z handler_name : Core Media Data Handler encoder : H.264 Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 84 kb/s (default) Metadata: creation_time : 2021-04-10T23:22:06.000000Z handler_name : Core Media Data Handler Stream #0:2(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default) Metadata: creation_time : 2021-04-10T23:22:06.000000Z handler_name : Core Media Data Handler Stream #0:3(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 0 kb/s (default) Metadata: creation_time : 2021-04-10T23:22:06.000000Z handler_name : Core Media Data Handler Stream #0:4(und): Data: none (mebx / 0x7862656D), 34 kb/s (default) Metadata: creation_time : 2021-04-10T23:22:06.000000Z handler_name : Core Media Data Handler [NULL @ 0x138e6e0] Unable to find a suitable output format for 'ff.log' ff.log: Invalid argument
```

Comment: Show the complete log from the ffmpeg command.

Comment: @llogan `var_dump($cmd)` is `NULL` , `print_r($cmd)` is `1` .

Comment: @llogan Thank you, please check https://prnt.sc/11j3k69

Comment: I tried, but the codes were in one line, not one under the other. that's why I took a screenshot.

Comment: @llogan Added in question

Comment: Can't help without the **complete** log. You're only providing a small segment. Use `ffmpeg -i video.mov -vcodec copy -acodec copy video.mp4 2> ff.log` and share `ff.log` contents.

Comment: @llogan Ok, i have edited the command line please check the question. Thank you

Comment: Is `input.mov` actually `https://dev.websiteaddress.com/uploads/files/2021-04-16/image_1618597539012465400_5.mov`? How is a CDN involved?

Comment: @llogan Yes it is `input.mov` actually `https://dev.websiteaddress.com/uploads/files/2021-04-16/image_1618597539012465400_5.mov` I don't know how the CDN is involved. But when I disable the CDN, it can convert vieo in ffmpeg mov format to mp4. Currently, video in mov format can be converted to 0-second mp4 format. And the file size gets too low.

Comment: The question is too vague and there isn't much info to help figure out the problem. So I only have generic suggestions: 1) FFmpeg 3.4.8 is old. Get a recent version. 2) Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options